# No iMovie Main Window

Tags: imovie

All of a sudden, starting up iMovie doesn't give me a main editing window. Most of the menu items are grayed out.

Mojave on a Mac Pro (Early 2008).

Comment: Please verify that you are indeed running Mojave on a Mac Pro early 2008 please, and not an earlier version of macOS.

Answer (score 1):

You're running an unsupported OS, things are likely to not work as expected. Just because you *can* squeeze Mojave onto an old Mac doesn't mean you *should*.
Mojave needs a Metal-capable GPU & iMovie is very probably using Metal.
Even a 5.1 can't run Mojave without one, let alone a 3,1.

The 3,1 isn't supposed to be able to run anything newer than El Cap, so why not try going back to that?